# MS Access subform comes up blank after main form refreshed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016, subform

I'm having a strange problem with my form that contains a subform (continuous view) with a visible property set to false unless a specific button is clicked. The main form is connected to a SQL table backend and when a new record is initiated the main form doesn't add an ID value right away (unless you use me.refresh). Once I put me.refresh in the code, and then make the subform visible it comes up as blank (i.e. no records found). However, if I were to open the same subform simultaneously as a regular form (outside of the main form), then it shows up fine. Also, when I remove me.refresh on the main form and toggle around by clicking on various fields in the datasheet section of a form(I use a split view) until the ID number is properly assigned and then make the subform visible, then it works fine.

Also, initially when I tested the database with all tables being local (no SQL backend connected), the subform was showing up correctly each time (because main form ID was generated right away).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what workaround I can use for this problem? Or perhaps if you could suggest a code one can use to push a form to generate autonumber ID without the use of Me.Refresh. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to refresh the subform ? because Me.refresh refers to the Main Form not the subform.

Comment: try like this  `Me.subform.Form.Requery`

Comment: Thanks Tarun. I tried Me.subformname.Form.Requery and the subform still comes up blank.

Comment: What about `Me.Requery`?

Comment: Is the subform also connected to SQL Server? If so, the Parent and Child controls in the SubForm control won't work. Refresh simply writes any changes to the current record to the database. Requery forces all the records meeting the criteria to be fetched again from the database.

Comment: @kismert: subform has a recordsource made of a query connected to local tables only. The problem as I see it, the subform on the main form can't see ID of the mainform right after me.refresh. If I open the main form on any already existing records, then the subform reflects data correction.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: me.requery just requeries the combo box that has an after update event which triggers a new record created. If I add it, then nothing happens - it just perpetually requeries the combo box.

Comment: @Rang - show us the code! Perpetual requerying is definitely  *not* normal Access behavior. You've likely accidentally setup a loop in your event code. But we're all just guessing until you give us specifics.